# logrus output in different formats

Tags: go, logrus

My program uses `logrus` in a basic way without any config:

```golang
   logrus.Info("...")
```

But in different places, it outputs in different formats, some place like:

```
INFO[0016] pushed
```

and some place like:

```
time="2023-11-30T05:26:39Z" level=info msg=pushed
```

I wonder what is a mistery behind?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you included code that reproduces this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me self-answer this question. I looked into `logrus` code in the weekend, and found the tricky.

`logrus` has a mechanism to detect if the current terminal is colored, if yes, it will output in format like `INFO[0000] pushed`, otherwise in format like `time="2023-11-30T05:26:39Z" level=info msg=pushed`.

So if you want to always output in the first format, which is shorter, then you just set force color:

```golang
    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{
        ForceColors: true,
    })
```

If you want the second format, then just force disable color:

```golang
    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.TextFormatter{
        DisableColors: true,
    })
```

You can also configure time format for sure.